# Jfrog uploading non-specified files

Tags: jenkins, pattern-matching, artifactory

In artifactory upload stage I have specified to upload certain text files only, but the rtUpload stage is also uploading files that are not mentioned in the file spec

```
{
   "pattern": "*contents.txt*",
   "target": "myrepo/artifacts/uploads/"
},
{
   "pattern": "*md5.txt*",
   "target": "myrepo/artifacts/uploads/"
}
```

The above code should upload only contents.txt and md5.txt files but it is also uploading files named catver.txt and mod.txt

Comment: Are the files catver.txt and mod.txt a part of the folder "uploads"?

Comment: Yes, in the source folder they are present, but in the file spec I have not mentioned to upload those files, however its still getting uploaded

Comment: Could you please try it out in the following format?      
"pattern": "artifacts/uploads/*contents.txt*",
"target": "myrepo/"